# Can't mock Date class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

i am using mockito and i have a custom date class and i want to be able to mock this date class in my test class, so i tried the following:

```
    MVDate date = Mockito.mock(MYDate.class);
    Mockito.when(date.get(Calendar.MONTH)).thenReturn(5);
```

**MYDate Class:**

```
public class MYDate extends GregorianCalendar implements Comparable<Calendar> {

public MYDate() {
        setTime(new Date());
    }

}
```

but when trying to print the `new MYDate();` it always prints the current date.
please advise how should i mock the calendar class so that i can test on specific date for all methods who create new data instance.

Comment: a Date is not a Calendar...

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can see what's happening?  If you're doing `new Date()`, then you won't be using your mock of `Calendar`.

Comment: @David Wallace i updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please note: I wrote this answer in 2013.  Things are a bit different now.  Basil Bourque's answer is the correct one.**

I would use a Factory class to make the `Date` objects, rather than using `new Date()`.  Have a second constructor for `MyDate` where you can pass the Factory.  Then use a mock of the Factory, which you can set up to return whatever date you like.

```
public class DateFactory{
    public Date makeDate(){
        return new Date();
    }
}

-----------------------------------

public class MyDate extends GregorianCalendar implements Comparable<Calendar>{

    public MyDate(){
        this(new DateFactory());
    }

    MyDate(DateFactory factory){
        setTime(factory.makeDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share how can i use the DateFactory in test ?

Comment: As I said.  You make a mock of the factory.  You stub it to return whatever date you want it to return, when you call `makeDate`.  In your test, you use the second `MyDate` constructor and pass in the mocked factory.

Answer (score 2):

So the need to write unit tests against code that gets the current date is very common. I fought against it numerous times and finally wrote a solution. My solution is to have a `DateSupplier` that wraps the call to `new Date()`. I then have a test class called `DateController` that allows unit tests to control what value `DateSupplier` returns.

Here are the links:
[DateSupplier](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/libex/src/main/java/org/libex/concurrent/DateSupplier.java)

[DateController](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/testlibex/src/main/java/org/libex/test/concurrent/DateController.java)

`DateSupplier` is written with a `static` method to get the `Date`. This prevents coders from having to import an instance all over the place.

`DateController` is written as a `Rule` that rests the behavior of `DateSupplier` back to the default behavior of returning `new Date()`.

Comment: `DateSupplier` could be named more elegantly : `Clock`.

Comment: @John B, what jar i should use for ParametersAreNonnullByDefault annotation on jboss ? also can i use the example without this annotation ?

Comment: Yes, the annotation is just documentation. It is provided in `jsr305`

Comment: This is almost impossible to implement in Kotlin as `getInstance()` is protected.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 `java.time.Clock` Class

The new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 includes a [`Clock`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class for this purpose of mocking the date-time during development and testing.

## Joda-Time

As I recall, the popular [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework also has a facility for faking the clock.

## Converting

You can easily convert between the date-time objects of both those frameworks and the java.util.Date class as needed for interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are mocking a specific method 'cal.get()'.

```
assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 5);
```

In this case, the above statement will be true, but cal.getTime() would return something different. Did you mean to mock cal.getTime() instead?